# spring security keeps redirected to it's default login page

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I am new to the Spring framework. Here, I have created my own login page, where a user should enter his or her username and password, which are stored in a database. So, username and password should match with the database values, only then the user can be redirected to another page, otherwise the same login page should displayed. But I don't understand what causes this, I keep getting Spring security login page instead of my own login page. Can anyone please give me a solution for this problem?

`@Configuration` class:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(
            "/**",
            "/js/**",
            "/css/**",
            "/img/**",
            "/webjars/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout()
        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .clearAuthentication(true)
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
        .permitAll();
}
```

`@Controller` Class:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String loginForm(Model model) {
        User user = new User();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home(Model model) {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

`@Service` class:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public User findByUserid(String userid) {
        return userRepository.findByUserid(userid);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUserid(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username or password.");
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUserid(),
                user.getPassword(), null);
    }
}
```

Comment: `loginProcessingUrl("/login").loginPage("/path_to/login_page.html")`. Have a look here: [spring-security-login](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login)

Comment: @DirkDeyne I've changed to my code like this .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .loginPage("/classpath:/templates/login.html")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .permitAll()          but, Nothing works, still got the same default login page.

Answer (score 0):

in your config file, you can do this

```
   .formLogin()
      .loginPage("/login")
      .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateUser")// call API for authenticate the user
      .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
      .permitAll();
```

In my case it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this:-

```
 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(  "/**",
        "/js/**",
        "/css/**",
        "/img/**",
        "/webjars/**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateUser")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            .permitAll();
}
```